# PHP - get and count all what is inside the stdClass

Tags: php

This is my array:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => stdClass Object 
       ( [form] => Change Dormitory 
         [data] => stdClass Object 
                 ( [element] => input
                   [name] => form-start 
                   [class] => form-control mdate 
                   [type] => text 
                   [label] => Start ) 
           [0] => stdClass Object 
                 ( [element] => input 
                   [name] => form-end 
                   [class] => form-control mdate 
                   [type] => text 
                   [label] => End ) 
)
```

I wanted to count all inside the `[data]` which is 2, but I dont know how to get it, and use it in `foreach`. My attempt:

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    foreach ($param_form as $value) {
        print_r($value);
    $i++;
    }
?>

count((array)$param_form[$i]->data);
```

How this made:

```
$form = array(
    array(
        'form' => 'Change Dormitory',
        'data' => array(
                        'element'=>'input',
                        'name'=>'form-start',
                        'class'=>'form-control mdate',
                        'type'=>'text',
                        'column'=>'col-md-4',
                        'label'=>'Start'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'element'=>'input',
                        'name'=>'form-end',
                        'class'=>'form-control mdate',
                        'type'=>'text',
                        'column'=>'col-md-4',
                        'label'=>'End'
                    ),

);

$new = json_encode($form);

$data = new stdClass;
$data->param_form = json_decode($new);

$this->load->view('my_view',$data);
```

Comment: Could just be a typo when you typed up the question but the `data` property is not valid syntax

Comment: That also cause me errors as well, I am new to this `foreach`, I wanted to do `for` but it needs indexing when i open it, so it looks like `$param_form[0]->data`

Comment: So you had better show us how you created that data structure

Comment: Okay so sorry about this

Comment: _Could just be a typo when you typed up the question but the `data` property is not valid syntax_. Or rather `data` and `0` are seperate properties of the outer object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is how you want to create your array

```
$form = array(
    array(
        'form' => 'Change Dormitory',
        'data' => array(
                    array(
                        'element'=>'input',
                        'name'=>'form-start',
                        'class'=>'form-control mdate',
                        'type'=>'text',
                        'column'=>'col-md-4',
                        'label'=>'Start'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'element'=>'input',
                        'name'=>'form-end',
                        'class'=>'form-control mdate',
                        'type'=>'text',
                        'column'=>'col-md-4',
                        'label'=>'End'
                    )
                ),

);
```

Now the `data` property will be an array containing 2 sub arrays, `[0] and [1]`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you need to make sure that your array is right `$form`. The key `data` needs to be an array to be counted and have items/array inside an array. Using a good text editor will definitely help if you're starting.

like

```
$form = array(
    array(
        'form' => 'Change Dormitory',
        'data' => array(
            array(),
            array(),
        ),
    ),
);
```

you can then count the items inside the data by
`echo count($data->param_form[0]->data);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$form = array(
    'form' => 'Change Dormitory',
    'data' => array(
        array(
            'element'=>'input',
            'name'=>'form-start',
            'class'=>'form-control mdate',
            'type'=>'text',
            'column'=>'col-md-4',
            'label'=>'Start'
        ),
        array(
            'element'=>'input',
            'name'=>'form-end',
            'class'=>'form-control mdate',
            'type'=>'text',
            'column'=>'col-md-4',
            'label'=>'End'
        ),
    ),
);

$data->param_form = $form;
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);
```

count: `echo count($param_form['data']);`

Comment: A code-onl answer with little explanation is not recomended.